# print similar word matches to the number using python

Tags: python, csv, logic

I have a text file which contains -

```
A 1 2 @ ~ 7 8 3 12389390  
B 1 3 6 ~ 1 1 9 -3 2 34789021 
C 4 5 ~ 2 4 1 1 $ -1 12389390
D 2 4 1 ~ 1 1 @ -1 6 @ 34789021
E 3 3 9 ~ 2 4 0 -1 2 12389390 34789021 25909052
```

The output should be -

```
A C E
B D E
E
```

Because the value of A,C,E have same numbers.

I have tried this code -

```
import re
maxline = 7
with open ('letter.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if re.match('^[a-zA-Z]+', line) is not None:
            print(line.split()[0])
                with open('letter.csv','a+') as output:
                output.write(line)
```

The outputs are like -

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

I just print the first letter of each line. But could not find any logic to do just like the output should be.Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Which columns/positions are eligbile for the equal number check? How do I know that A's number is 12389390 but E's numbers are 12389390 34789021 25909052, for example?

Comment: What does "A,C,E have same numbers" mean?

Comment: @galmeriol A, C and E all have the number 12389390 in their line. B, D and E share 34789021. Finally, only E has 25909052. The problem however is that we haven't been told at which column we may start to look for these numbers.

Comment: @timgeb Actually I am also searching this problem's solution. There is no specific positions to check the equal numbers. Thats why i am asking the question. :(

Comment: Is the similarity between lines depend only large numbers? Because A and B also have 1 in common.

Comment: @jahan this is a definition problem, not a programming problem. Why do you NOT want to print A B C D E because all of them share the number 1? How is the accepted answer supposed to be "correct"?

Comment: The same keys or unique numbers for ex: 12389390 make this sequence(A,C,E). I have also several data in this text file which does not have any number like 1 but have the same keys(unique numbers).@timgeb

Comment: The similarity occurs only for this large numbers. @galmeriol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want to do : 
you need to find all the key sequences in your string i.e "12389390" like keys and i assume its length = 8. 
Find All the unique keys and loop over you file for check which line contains the current key, then get first element of that line. You are done.

```
import re    
numberToMatch = []
saveValues = {}
with open("D:\\untitled\\data.txt") as dataF :

            lines = dataF.readlines()
            for line in lines :
                print(line)
                numMatch = re.findall(r"[0-9]{8}(?![0-9])", line.rstrip())
                print(numMatch)
                for num in numMatch :
                    saveValues[num] = []

            for key_ in saveValues.keys() :
                        for line in lines:
                                if key_ in line :
                                    saveValues[key_].append(line.rstrip().split(" ")[0])


for k,v in saveValues.items():
    print (" ".join(x for x in v))
```

**Output**

```
A C E
B D E
E
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This code works perfectly. But I can't understand this line  `" ".join(x for x in v)` . Can you please explain?

Comment: `" ".join(x for x in v)` this statement is just traversing the list and appending the values with " "  .e.g a  v is a list that has i.e v =  ["A", "B","C"] .
`" ".join(x for x in v)`  will give you a space separated string i.e "A B C". In Simple words conversion from list of strings to spaced separated strings.